# How to properly get buildozer set up?

Tags: java, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

So I've been trying to use the *buildozer* tool in order to build my python3 kivy calculator application for mobile platforms. Here is the main python source file and the 'calc.kv' file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
import kivy
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class CalcRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CalcRoot, self).__init__()

    def calc_symbol(self, symbol):
        self.calc_field.text += symbol

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self.calc_field.text = ""

    def get_result(self):
        try:
            self.calc_field.text = str(eval(self.calc_field.text))
        except SyntaxError:
            self.calc_field.text = "Cannot parse expression"

class MyCalc(App):
    def build(self):
        return CalcRoot()

def main():
    kivy.require('1.9.0')
    Window.size = (640, 700)
    mycalc = MyCalc()
    mycalc.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- The calc.kv file:

```
<CalcRoot>

    calc_field: calc_field

    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: calc_field
        height: 200
        size_hint: (1, None)
        readonly: True
        disabled: True
        font_size: 64

    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        columns: 4
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        height: 400
        size_hint: (1, None)
        Button:
            text: '1'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('1')
        Button:
            text: '2'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('2')
        Button:
            text: '3'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('3')
        Button:
            text: '+'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('+')
        Button:
            text: '4'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('5')
        Button:
            text: '5'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('5')
        Button:
            text: '6'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('6')
        Button:
            text: '-'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('-')
        Button:
            text: '7'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('7')
        Button:
            text: '8'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('8')
        Button:
            text: '9'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('9')
        Button:
            text: 'x'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('*')
        Button:
            text: '('
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('(')
        Button:
            text: '0'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('0')
        Button:
            text: ')'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol(')')
        Button:
            text: '÷'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('/')

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        padding: 7
        spacing: 7
        height: 100
        size_hint: (1, None)
        Button:
            text: '.'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.calc_symbol('.')
        Button:
            text: 'C'
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.clear()
        Button:
            text: '='
            font_size: 26
            on_press: root.get_result()
```

Everything was going great up until I actually tried running the `buildozer -v android debug` command. I read in buildozer's documentation that it will work, and even if I don't have all the java dependencies installed, it will pull them for me and install them. However, I seem to be getting the following error:

```
/opt/jdk-20.0.1/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager: line 172: /opt/jdk-20.0.1/bin/java: Success
# Command failed: ['/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager', '--sdk_root=/home/borat/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk', 'platform-tools']
# ENVIRONMENT:
<and then it lists out a bunch of my environment variables>
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried googling the problem, and even tried multiple search engines, but I only find sketchy forums telling me that I need to reinstall java, but that doesn't solve anything....